# Is it possible to make entire border of input mat form field fill red on validation error

Tags: css, mat-form-field, angular-material-8, mat-error

In my form i have email field which is customized and i cant use outline appearance input field .

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="pat@example.com" [formControl]="email" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

On validation if there is an error , it appears as below

[image]

Is it possible to make it appear as below highlighting entire input field

[image]

I could see lot of example for outline appearance form field but not for fill appearance . Can someone guide. TIA

**Update:**

tried below css still i couldn't able to achieve .

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-flex {
  border: 4px solid red !important ;
}
```

would be helpful if there is any hack to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-flex {
  border: 2px solid red !important;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

You need to use `::ng-deep` to get the desired result. [Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mznpx7-99uk7g?file=app/form-field-error-example.css).
Let me know if face any issue.

Comment: Yeah.. I was using ViewEncapsulation:none in my components and forgot to add over here in particular component .. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Can we apply the same using ngClass on mat form field. Something like [ngClass]=".mat-form-field-flex : 'onCostBelowAvg' " ?

Comment: Yes you can definitely add a class on mat-form-field by using ngClass but it won't be possible to get your desired result. Since you must apply the css when the form is invalid right.

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer if it was useful for you.